# normal distribution in 2D polar coordinates - why is the expected value not zero?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There is something I don't get. Say I have a probability density function:
$$f\left(x,y\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^{2}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}e^{-\frac{y^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}$$

Now, in polar coordinates:

$$f(r) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^{2}}e^{-\frac{r^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}$$

But if I calculate the expected value of this probability density function, I don't get 0. Why is it? intuitively, that is the peak of the gaussian so that's what is most probable. It is this way with a one dimensional gaussian centered at the origin, but why isn't it the case here?

Comment: Because you lack a $r$ in the function $f(r)$, which is come from the change of variables  $$dxdy = rdrd\theta$$

Comment: I'm aware of the Jacobian, do you mean to say the expected value indeed shouldn't be zero and you give an explanation for it? Can it be intuitively explained somehow?

Comment: Perhaps I came to the conclusion too quick. You wanted to calculate $E(R) = E(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2})$ right? If yes, this expectation is not equal to $0$. If no, you could write the variable that you want to calculate its expected value ($E( ??)$)?

Comment: Right, it isn't equal to 0, but why intuitively? The gaussian is centered around the origin, why is it different from the one dimensional case of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ ?

Comment: $R > 0$ then $E(R)$ must be greater than $0$. For the case of univariate normal distribution, $X$ is a symmetrical variable (and also can receive negative value).
Having a symetrical density function doesn't suffice to garantee that the Expected value is equal to 0,

Comment: @Darkenin Show me a point on the plane where $r<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have computed as $f(r)$ is incorrect, not only just for the reason pointed out in the comment by NN2, but because what you would have found if you had done the transformation correctly is that if the joint density of two variables $X$ and $Y$ is
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right),\tag{1}$$ then the *joint density* of $R =\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ and $\Theta = {\mathsf{atan2}}(X,Y)$ is
$$f_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot r\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}2\right), \quad 0 \leq r < \infty, 0\leq \theta < 2\pi,\tag{2}$$
where $$f_R(r) = r\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}2\right),\quad 0 \leq r < \infty \tag{3}$$ is a Rayleigh density, and $$f_\Theta(\theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi},\quad 0\leq \theta < 2\pi,\tag{4}$$ is a *uniform* density (and also showing that $R$ and $\Theta$ are *independent* random variables_).

It is not clear what you understand as the *expected value* of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ but if you mean $(E[X],E[Y])$ being $(0,0)$, then you need to understand that neither $E[R]$ nor $E[\Theta]$ equal $0$. Note that $f_R(r) = 0$ for $r\leq 0$ which means that all the probability mass lies to the right of the origin, implying that $E[R]>0$. Nor is $0$ the *mode* of the Rayleigh density.

Answer (score 0):

Think about rings of different sizes, centered on the origin. In all cases let's suppose that the thickness of the ring is dr. A ring of some small radius (0.1, say) has an area of 2 pi 0.1 dr; a ring of a large radius (eg 10) has an area of 2 pi 10 dr. So certainly if the x and y were uniform random variables, the rings corresponding to larger values of r would have larger areas and therefore higher probabilities. In the case that the x and y are Gaussians centered on the origin, there is still an effect of increasing area as r gets larger (and decreasing area as r gets closer to 0). That is why even though when you look at a 2D gaussian point cloud, the densest part is the center [ie at the origin], it is still the case that p(r==0) = 0...the size of the "ring" at 0 radius is so small there there is essentially no probability of selecting that specific spot, even though that specific spot is more probable than any other single 0 dimensional spot on the plane. As you move away from the center, the rings increase in area and so the probability of picking a point on a larger ring increases. As you go out further still (past ring with the max probability), the individual Gaussians get very low in probability, so the chance of having a very large r becomes very small.